# FileInputStream.available() returns bytes but ObjectInputStream.available() returns 0

Tags: java, file, stream, inputstream, objectinputstream

I ran into a weird problem which I don't seem to understand.
I'm making a program which reads data from a file. But when I do read data, I immediately receive an EOFException.

So I checked with .available() if the file was empty or not. And I got a weird result. The FileInputStream said that the file was filled (249 bytes), but the ObjectInputStream said that the file is empty (or can't be read).

EOFException at: "int signatureSize = ois.readInt();"

```
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("input(signedbyLK).ext");
        System.out.println("fin available: " + fin.available());

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
        System.out.println("ois avaiable: " + ois.available());

        int signatureSize = ois.readInt();
        byte[] sigBytes = (byte[]) ois.readObject();
        String text = (String) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
```

EDIT: I'm adding content to the file like this:

```
        File newFile = new File("input(signedbyLK).ext");
        newFile.createNewFile();

        System.out.println("Succesfully created new file: " + newFile.getName());

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(newFile));
        oos.writeObject(sigBytes.length);
        oos.writeObject(sigBytes);
        oos.writeObject(readInput());
        oos.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what the javadoc says

> Any attempt to read object data which exceeds the boundaries of the
>   custom data written by the corresponding writeObject method will cause
>   an OptionalDataException to be thrown with an eof field value of true.
>   Non-object reads which exceed the end of the allotted data will
>   reflect the end of data in the same way that they would indicate the
>   end of the stream: bytewise reads will return -1 as the byte read or
>   number of bytes read, and primitive reads will throw EOFExceptions. If
>   there is no corresponding writeObject method, then the end of default
>   serialized data marks the end of the allotted data.

Also, you need to read the object input stream in the same order as when you serialized it

Comment: I've edited my question. Now you can see in which order I fill the file.

Comment: Your read calls are not even corresponding to the write calls. Your first write call is an object, but your first read is an int

Comment: Wow, I didn't even notice that. Thank you!